# unbind default key from inputrc

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline, inputrc

What I want to do is made C-h not send backwards-delete-char

there is nothing about it in my inputrc files but is shows up in bind -p

Comment: It is default for both vi and emacs mode, check ``man readline | grep "C-H"
``. Try adding ```"\C-h": ""``` to your ``~/.inputrc`` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-h` is bound to `backward-delete-char` by default. If you don't like that, bind it to a different command in your `.inputrc`, e.g.

```
"\C-h": nop
```

to make it do nothing.

Note that if your terminal sends C-h for the <kbd>BackSpace</kbd> key¹, and `C-h` is not explicitly bound to an existing command (so not `nop`), then `C-h` will execute `backward-delete-char`.

¹  <sub>More precisely, if your terminal's configuration tell applications that this is so. This is the `erase` character in the stty settings. You can display stty settings by running `stty -a`.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Binding to the `nop` will suppress the key action, but won't help in case you want to free up the key to be a prefix. Suppose you want to dedicate "M-c" as a prefix to a set of related macros, for example, such that the sequence "M-c M-i" is bound to a macro that simply types a long command `controlct sensor instance`. Naturally, "M-c M-d" would print something else, and so on.

But there is a default binding `"\ec": capitalize-word"`, that would stand in your way. If you print the key sequence "M-c M-i" fast enough (specifically, within the time in milliseconds set by the `keyseq-timeout` readline variable), you'll get the desired behavior. But if you linger, bash will execute the "M-c" default binding alone, i. e. the `nop` command. So in this case, you really need to *unbind* the key, not *rebind* it to something that does nothing.

Fortunately, readline supports that quite easily (@user996142 provided the correct syntax and a reference in a comment):

```
"\ec":
```

alone on a line by itself. This clears the binding.

**Warning time:** *Do* restart bash (e. g., `exec bash -l`), not just reload the `.inputrc` file with "C-x C-r". readline may not *report* the binding after the reload (`bind -l` does not show it, and `bind -q capitalize-word` happily reports "capitalize-word is not bound to any keys," but still times out it, just as if it were bound to `nop`. This is a bug in some versions of either bash or readline.

Comment: this answer should have been the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

I had to unbind using the following.  The elusive important piece for me was adding the surrounding single quotes.

FWIW, numerous variations work when running the command directly in the shell.  But when including the command in .inputrc or a .sh file, this is the only thing that I found to work.

**Alt-c**

```
'"\ec":'
```

**Ctrl-c**

```
'"\C-c":'
```

The following `-u <readline command name>` also seems to work *sometimes*.

```
bind -u yank
bind '"\C-y":'
```

Comment: note the syntax is slightly different for .inputrc files vs the shell, so you won't find something that works for both (`bind` command and surrounding single quotes needed in the shell). Using this syntax in inputrc results in `readline: \`'': missing closing quote for macro`.