# Bash: pressing escape 4 times

Tags: bash

When I press escape 4 times in a bash terminal, it displays something like this:

```
-bash-4.1$
Display all 2837 possibilities? (y or n)
:
!
./
[
[[
]]
{
}
411toppm
a2p
ac
accept
accton
aclocal
aclocal-1.11
acpi_listen
```

What is this feature, and how are these entries found? (On the second esc press, the terminal gives an audible alert.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$ bind -p | grep 'complete$'
"\C-i": complete
"\M-\e": complete
```

This shows that the default key binding of <kbd>Meta+Esc</kbd> (and <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd>) in Emacs command line editing mode is the Readline function `complete`.  The <kbd>Meta</kbd> key is usually <kbd>Esc</kbd> on keyboards without an explicit <kbd>Meta</kbd> key.  The Readline documentation for this function says

> Attempt to perform completion on the text before point.  The
>                 actual completion performed is application-specific.  Bash, for
>                 instance, attempts completion treating the text as a variable
>                 (if the text begins with `$`), username (if the text begins with
>                 `~`), hostname (if the text begins with `@`), or command (including
>                 aliases and functions) in turn.  If none of these produces a
>                 match, filename completion is attempted.  Gdb, on the other
>                 hand, allows completion of program functions and variables, and
>                 only attempts filename completion under certain circumstances.

---

Regarding your comment to [Anthon's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391928/116858): No, pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice is not the same as pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> generally (unless it's in a program that maps them both to the same action, as Readline does by default). However <kbd>Ctrl+i</kbd> *is* the same as <kbd>Tab</kbd>, just like <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Esc</kbd>.  This means that you can do completion with <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd> in `bash` if you wish, as long as double <kbd>Esc</kbd> is bound to the Readline `complete` function. This is handy if you're working at a VT220 terminal, for example, which lacks the Escape key:

[image: German VT220 keyboard]

Comment: Kusalananda, thank you for this in-depth answer. About your last point: why is pressing `Esc` twice (or `\M-\e`) not the same as `Tab` in bash, if both do completion?

Comment: @flow2k It is the same if both Esc-Esc and Tab are bound to the `complete` function, which they are by default, but not generally (i.e. the key-presses are not "the same"). You can't substitute Tab with Esc-Esc everywhere, only in readline-capable programs. However, you may substitute Tab with Ctrl-i or Esc with Ctrl-[ anywhere.

Comment: A followup if I may: I don't see `Tab` in the output of `bind -p`. Why is that? Maybe because `Tab` is "hardcoded" and can't be bound?

Comment: @flow2k No, Tab is _identical_ to Ctrl-i. Look for `\C-i`. This is an equivalence on the hardware level.

Comment: How to unbind this default mapping?

Comment: Found the solution for unbinding: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/527020/337515

Answer (score 8):

That is called file completion, and if you don't have any preceding command on the commandline, bash will offer you to complete all 2837 commands it knows about, both built-in and the ones found in your `PATH`

The are presented in sorted order

Comment: Interesting - so this is the same as pressing tab twice. Perhaps 2 escapes = 1 tab?